# How to pipe a null separated string into an array in bash?

Tags: bash

Given a command that outputs multiple strings separated by bytes, whats the best (fastest) way to convert this into an array in bash.

eg: `git ls-files -z`

Comment: That is the right approach

Comment: Is `IFS= ` really necessary? `help readarray` (or rather `help mapfile`) suggests that `IFS` is not used since `mapfile` doesn't use wordsplitting like `read`, but always splits on newlines or the symbols given by `-d`.

Comment: Question had answer included, was: 
This works but seems a bit clunky: `IFS= readarray -t -d '' MY_ARRAY < <(git ls-files -z)`

Could include this as an answer instead.

Comment: @Socowi, you're right, `IFS` isn't needed. Thanks

Comment: ...mind you, I don't generally advise judging quality of bash code on "clunkiness", if you consider clunkiness and verbosity to be one and the same; the historical legacy of compatibility with decades of shells (and, occasionally, formalized standards) with conflicting, oft-poorly-considered semantics means that a substantial amount of defensive programming is often called for if one wants robust, predictable behavior. Consequently, *longer* code can often be easier for fellow developers to reason about, if that verbosity is used to foreclose potential corner cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For bash 4.4 and later only:

```
readarray -d '' array < <(git ls-files -z)
```

For backwards compatibility with bash 3.x and 4.0 through 4.3:

```
array=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
  array+=( "$item" )
done < <(git ls-files -z)
```

Comment: Why `IFS=`? Won't `IFS` be ignored if there is only one variable to read into?

Comment: @WillPalmer, not _quite_ ignored -- you still get leading and trailing whitespace stripped.